# What is the closest alternative to the .Net NotSupportedException in C++

Tags: c++, exception, stl, std

What is the closest alternative to the .Net NotSupportedException in the standard library? If I have to create one of my own what should it logically derive from?

Comment: Sounds like an `std::runtime_error` to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard gives you

```
namespace std {
class logic_error;
class domain_error;
class invalid_argument;
class length_error;
class out_of_range;
class runtime_error;
class range_error;
class overflow_error;
class underflow_error;
}
```

As Jerry said runtime_error is the best match of those, so derive from that.